# Demo for iron-scroll-target-behavior in Polymer 2.x

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x, demo, iron-elements

I need to direct the browser to scroll to the top of the page. I think `iron-scroll-target-behavior` might be a good choice. But I can't find any working demos.

Can anyone locate or point me to a working demo of the iron-scroll-target-behavior element?

[Here is the element on webcomponents.org.](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-scroll-target-behavior)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `scroll-target-behavior`, I'm just using the platform and going with: `scrollIntoView()`. [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

example

```
const element = document.getElementById("box");

element.scrollIntoView();
element.scrollIntoView(false);
element.scrollIntoView({block: "end"});
element.scrollIntoView({behavior: "instant", block: "end", inline: "nearest"});
```

Or, to scroll to the top of the page:

```
document.body.scrollIntoView({
  behavior: "smooth",
  block: "top",
})
```